# Initialize static constexpr member variable of class template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, c++14, constexpr

Here is the situation: A class `Foo` with a template param `int N` has a static member variable `float val`. The value of `val` is corresponding to `N` and never changes, so I expect it to be `constexpr`.

I know the common way of initializing static constexpr member variable is:

```cpp
// ok, but not what I want
template <int N>
struct Foo {
    static constexpr float val { 0.0f };
};
template <int N>
constexpr float Foo<N>::val;
```

But because `val` is initialized **inside** the class scope, I cannot specify different `val` for different `N`.

If `val` is not `constexpr` but `const`, this works:

```cpp
// ok, but not what I want
template <int N>
struct Foo {
    static const float val;
};
template <>
const float Foo<0>::val = 3.14f;
template <>
const float Foo<1>::val = 0.1f;
```

But then I can't use `constexpr float val = Foo<0>::val;`, because `Foo<0>::val` is not a constant expression.

So, the goal I want to achieve is something like below:

```cpp
// the thing I want, but error
template <int N>
struct Foo {
    static constexpr float val;
};
template <>
constexpr float Foo<0>::val = 3.14f;
template <>
constexpr float Foo<1>::val = 0.1f;
```

But the compiler complains:

> error: declaration of constexpr static data member 'val' requires an initializer

And if I add an initializer for `val` (`static constexpr float val { 0.0f };`), the compiler says:

> error: duplicate initialization of 'Foo<0>::val'
> error: duplicate initialization of 'Foo<1>::val'

How ironic :D

A workaround I know is using [variable template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) (C++14):

```cpp
// ok
struct Foo {
    template <int N>
    static constexpr float val { 0.0f };
};
template <>
constexpr float Foo::val<0> = 3.14f;
template <>
constexpr float Foo::val<1> = 0.1f;
```

This works as expected, for now. But if other members (variables or functions) in `Foo` still need the template param (i.e. `Foo` need to be class template), this solution is not applicable.

Any idea about this? Solutions using C++ standard below C++20 are preferred (C++20 is just too new for my project).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specialize the class template as

```
template <int N>
struct Foo {
    static constexpr float val { 0.0f };
};
template <>
struct Foo<0> {
    static constexpr float val { 3.14f };
};
template <>
struct Foo<1> {
    static constexpr float val { 0.1f };
};
```

Or make a function helper for initialization.

```
template <int N>
struct Foo {    
    static constexpr float get_val() {
        if constexpr (N == 0) return 3.14f;
        else if constexpr (N == 1) return 0.1f;
        else return 0.0f;
    }
    static constexpr float val { get_val() };
};
```